# How to force python commands to run together before context switch?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 2 processes running, and each is printing a config file it owns. The config file has no unique data I can trace, so I have no way of knowing which process printed what.

The way for me to handle that was adding a prefix print:

```
def print_config(proc_name):
    print(proc_name)
    print_conf()

# both processes are given the target print_config,
# args='a' or 'b', and then are started
```

However, the OS is ordering the commands in the following order:

```
1. Proc A: print(proc_name)
2. Proc B: print(proc_name)
3. Proc ?: print_conf()
4. Proc ??: print_conf()
```

How can I combine the prints, so I will see the print(proc_name) and immediately after the print_conf?

Comment: You have 2 processes, but they share the same stdout? Or do those processes write to the same file?

Comment: they both write to the same fd

Comment: According to additional info you've provided in comment and edited question, I've added a bit more info in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lock objects for execution control of your threads. Basically, the principle is to lock an global object before printing and release it when you finish with printing, so that other thread can access it and successively lock it and do the printing itself. Here's one of the examples (taken from [bogotobogo.com](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Lock_Objects_Acquire_Release.php)):

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, start = 0):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.value = start
    def increment(self):
        logging.debug('Waiting for a lock')
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired a lock')
            self.value = self.value + 1
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released a lock')
            self.lock.release()

def worker(c):
    for i in range(2):
        r = random.random()
        logging.debug('Sleeping %0.02f', r)
        time.sleep(r)
        c.increment()
    logging.debug('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = Counter()
    for i in range(2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(counter,))
        t.start()

    logging.debug('Waiting for worker threads')
    main_thread = threading.currentThread()
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        if t is not main_thread:
            t.join()
    logging.debug('Counter: %d', counter.value)
```

UPDATE:

In addition, if you are not asking about locking threads, then actually manipulating the output of two independent scripts, concept is quite the same, except you can use lock file for that purpose. Lets say you have two pretty similar scripts:
First one:

```
import os.path

while(os.path.exists("lock.LCK")):
        continue


f = open("lock.LCK", "w+")
file_for_output = open("output.txt", "a")
file_for_output.write("Hi2\n")
file_for_output.write("There2\n")
f.close()
os.remove("lock.LCK")
file_for_output.close()
```

And another one:

```
import os.path

while(os.path.exists("lock.LCK")):
        continue


f = open("lock.LCK", "w+")
file_for_output = open("output.txt", "a")
file_for_output.write("Hi1\n")
file_for_output.write("There1\n")
f.close()
os.remove("lock.LCK")
file_for_output.close()
```

If you would run those 2 files at a same time, 1 would have to wait until other one finishes the writing, because of the lock file protection in dead while loop. Please note that this is only basic example how this issue can be handled. If you would like to implement this in the real code, I really advise setting up the timeout limit for the dead loop and proper exceptions.